# Is icalcs inherrently installed on all Windows systems?

Tags: windows

I am updating an old calcs bat file for the modern age and am wondering if icalcs is always on all builds of Windows or if I need to redistribute it.

Comment: You can't legally redistribute it. Not unless you write your own version from scratch.

Comment: It is on all currently supported versions of Windows, i.e., from Vista onwards.  If you still have to support XP you'll have to stick to cacls.